# Do Docker support 32 bit ubuntu(12.04) or suse OS in future?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, docker-registry

We have some applications deployed in 32bit OS of Ubuntu(12.04) and Suse. And applications have some dependencies on 32bit OS and cannot migrate to 64 bit. 
I am planning to use Docker for deployment but current it does not support 32 bit.
So i want to know, whether docker is planning to support 32 bit OS in future and when??

or

If docker is not supporting 32 bit OS in future then please suggest alternate solution for my problem.

Comment: As far as I can tell, latest info on 32 bit is here https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/136

Answer (score 1):

There is not official support for 32 bits images (nor Docker daemon) from Docker, and it seems this is not a priority in short term (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/136). Anyway if it is important to you you can compile Docker to x86 and then use a base image of 32 bits to build your container with your 32bits app. You can find how to compile Docker for x86 architecture and how to build a 32 bits base image in [this post](http://mwhiteley.com/linux-containers/2013/08/31/docker-on-i386.html).

Comment: It is also possible to use 32-bit with 64-bit OS and docker. And linux32 utility helps if you need architecture reported as 32 bit.